# Proof gone wrong: Probability Generating functions.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification, generating-functions

I'm trying to proof something but I'm getting a different answer than my textbook and I don't know where I've gone wrong.

The question concerns a random discrete variable $Y$ taking on values in $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$ with a probability generating function $G_Y(s)$. If we define the sequence $U_n = \mathbb{P}(Y > n)$, it *should* follow that its generating function $U(s)$ satisfies:

$(1-s)U(s) = 1 - G_Y(s)$

However, I'm getting a different result, and I've gone throught it several times not getting why it's wrong (or it's just an erratum in my textbook)

My proof is as follows: By definition we have 
$G_Y(s) =  \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (\mathbb{P}(Y=i) \cdot s^i = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} ((\mathbb{P}(Y > i)-\mathbb{P}(Y > i-1)) \cdot s^i = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (\mathbb{P}(Y > i) \cdot s^i) - \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (\mathbb{P}(Y > i-1) \cdot s^i)=$

$ U(s) - ((\mathbb{P}(Y > -1) \cdot s^0 + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\mathbb{P}(Y>i-1) \cdot s^i) =$

Now we say $i = k+1$

$U(s) - 1 - \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (\mathbb{P}(Y>k) \cdot s^{k+1}) =
 U(s) - 1 - s \cdot \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (\mathbb{P}(Y>k) \cdot s^{k})=$

$ U(s) - 1 - s \cdot U(s) = (1-s) \cdot U(s) -1 = G_Y(s)$

So $1- G_Y(s) = 2 - (1-s) \cdot U(s)$
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is $$P(Y=i)=P(Y>i)-P(Y>i-1),$$ which should be the other way around: $$P(Y=i)=P(Y>i-1)-P(Y>i).\tag1$$ Argue this way: If $Y$ is greater than $i-1$, then either it's equal to $i$, or greater than $i$. Now rearrange that statement to get (1).

Comment: Oh wow of course, I wonder why I didn't see that haha, Thanks!